# xampp - localhost/websites/ will not open but localhost/phpmyadmin/ works fine - no port issue

Tags: apache, server, xampp, localhost

I have tried and tried to find an answer everywhere and tried most, if not all, possible remedies. Apache is the application using port 80, mySQL is using 3306. The xampp control panel and cmd/netstat -abno verify that. Changing the ports makes no difference. I have tried 3 browsers. The browsers suggest checking the connection and proxy and those are not an issue. It does not need an internet connection to work and there is no proxy server between my browser and C:\xampp\htdocs\   This server was working not so long ago. I am stumped with this one. I noticed a difference with the xampp control panels between this and another computer... This one says Apache is using 80, 883 and the other says 80, 443.

Answer (score 0):

I added that last sentence about the "883" later when I tried a copy of the site on another computer. It looks like I had changed that number in the http-ssl.conf file some time in the past and I had left a note in there about it. So... I did it to myself. I changed it back to 443 and that did it.